# Angular 6 convert group form to get request query parameters

Tags: angular, rest, angular6

I have a question I want to get some information by request to Web API using get and as a parameters I want the information that is in the form (as a filter form).

So request is simple:

```
  filterEvents() {
    this.http
      .get(environment.apiUrl + 'events/GetFilteredAxmCardsId', { params: { filter: this.filterFormGroup.value } })
      .subscribe(result => {
        this.axmCardIds = result.json() as number[];
      }, error => console.error(error));

    console.log(this.filterFormGroup.value);
  }
```

But here I have a problem passing form group values url looks like

```
GetFilteredEvents?filter={"AxmCards":[9,7]}
```

Of course object can have couple of more properties.

Well it does not look good, I could manually parameters, but its a lot of work and upkeep, so is there an easy way to parse such an object to get query parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the URL Search Params :

```
import {URLSearchParams} from '@angular/http';

...

let params = new URLSearchParams();
for(let key in this.filterFormGroup.value){
    params = params.set(key, this.filterFormGroup.value[key]);
}
this.http
  .get(environment.apiUrl + 'events/GetFilteredAxmCardsId', { params })
```